# Duda con los servlets de java y sql

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, sql-server-2012

En este servlet pequeño estoy introduciendo los valores en duro y quisiera que los valores en duro tuvieran parámetros para que se pueda almacenar la información ya que ésta sería del lado del cliente donde esta información se introduce.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    InsertarPublicacion ObtenerIdRedSh= new InsertarPublicacion(pool);
    String id=ObtenerIdRedSh.procedure("Nota:De Juan Barragan") ;
    response.getOutputStream().write(id.getBytes());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener los parámetros del objeto request. Ejemplo:

```xhtml
<form method='POST' action='/EjemploServlet'>
    <label for='nombre'>Ingrese su nombre: </label>
    <!--
        Lo principal para identificar al parámetro es el atributo 'name', no el id
    -->
    <input type='text' id='nombre' name='nombre' />
</form>
```

Luego, en tu servlet, tendrías este código:

```
@WebServlet("/EjemploServlet")
public class PruebaServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        String nombre = req.getParameter("nombre"); //<-- Ojo, se identifica por el campo 'name' del <input>
        System.out.println(String.format("Valor de parámetro 'nombre': %s", nombre));
        //usa el valor del parámetro para lo que necesites...
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias hoy lo pruebo