# problemas con mi codigo serveletes en los parametros

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, jdbc

hola que tal  tengo problemas con mi código del servlet ya que aquí donde dice cuenta es un parámetro de mi tabla y  de hecho antes de poner lo que está en el goGET yo había puesto algo así

```
 //InsertarPublication ObtenerIdRedS= new InsertarPublication(pool);    
//String id=ObtenerIdRedIM.procedure("juan barragan") ;
//response.getOutputStream().write(id.getBytes());
```

lo anterior está en el doGet y me regresaba un valor int que es el que necesito que retorne pero eso era solo poner un parámetro en duro y yo quería asignarle un parámeto que del lado del cliente pueda ingresar

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String cadena = (String)req.getAttribute("cuenta");        
    resp.getWriter().print("<p> RedKM" + cadena + "</p>");  
   req.getSession().setAttribute("cuenta",new Integer(22));     
}   
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
}

}
```

Comment: En base a tus preguntas https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/95265/227 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/95416/227 puedo notar que tu problema es comprender cómo funcionan los servlets. La vista (JSP) solo puede enviar parámetros a un servlets, los cuales se obtienen usando `HttpServletRequest#getParameter`, no con `HttpServletRequest#getAttribute`.

Comment: hola que tal si de echo si me cuesta un poco entender los pero  los puse asi y aun asi pero me arria error


String cadena = (String)req.getParameter("cuenta");        

  ((Object) req.getSession()).setParameter("cuenta",new Integer(22));